# How can I reliably parse git branch output to capture just the branch name?

Tags: bash, git

I'm running automated tests when a push to GitHub occurs.

As I setup the repo for testing, I can run:

```
git branch -a --contains <<commit id>>
```

to detect what branches the commit may exist in.

Git produces output like:

```
remotes/origin/MEM-5286-partner-video-update01
remotes/origin/MEM-5286-partner-video-update02
```

Can someone suggest an approach, using bash, to capture the branch names (`MEM-5286-partner-video-update01`, `MEM-5286-partner-video-update02`) from the end of the output strings?

I can load a bash array with the resultant lines, but have fallen flat trying to use sed and/or regex to capture just the branch names. There doesn't appear to be a git option to eliminate the remotes/origin prefix.

I would appreciate any thoughts on an approach.

Comment: you don't parse git branch, use something like git for-each-ref --contains <commit> --format="(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`--format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---formatltformatgt) option, the documentation for which is in under [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt):

```
git branch -a --contains <commit_id> --format='%(refname:short)'
```

`refname:short` has been introduced in [Git 1.6.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.1.txt#L142).

Comment: I added this to my updated answer, but even closer to OP's requirements (I believe): `--format "%(refname:lstrip=-1)"`

Comment: @JNevill That breaks if your branch names contain slashes.

Comment: That's terrible. So all that format function is doing is strtok'ing? That is shameful.

Comment: @JNevill  Thanks very much, that works - our branch naming is well defined and doesn't include the use of slashes. Cheers.

Comment: @shamca We use slashes in branch names at work, that's how I realized it :/

Answer (score 1):

Using native `git`. You can hit up the manpage for `git-for-each-ref` to see the atoms that can be used in the `--format` option here, but in short you can request the right-most part of the `refname` (branch name) using:

```
git branch -a --contains <<commit id>> --format "%(refname:lstrip=-1)"
```

---

Optionally using awk (which fails if the branch name contains a slash):

```
git branch -a --contains <<commit id>> | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

That splits the incoming lines by `"/"` and then prints the last field `print $NF`.

Comment: This answer does not account for the fact that branches can have `/` characters as part of their names.  This works great for the branch names that the OP mentions, but falls short in many cases. Check out [naming rules](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html) in the man pages: 

`They can include slash / for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot . or end with the sequence .lock.`

Comment: @mrfred That's a good catch. I have updated the answer to use the `--format` option of `git branch` command.